How sensitive are maximum-size matchings to edge deletion in random graphs?
My question concerns the sensitivity of maximum-size matchings (and more generally maximum-size $k$-cycle collections) to deletion of an edge in the graph.
Given a graph $G$, let a $k$-cycle be a cycle in the graph of length at most $k$. Let a $k$-allocation be a collection of disjoint $k$-cycles. For an allocation $A$ and node $v$, let $A(v)$ be the cycle containing $v$, where $A(v) = \varnothing$ if $v$ is not in a cycle. Let $G\setminus e$ be the graph obtained by deleting the edge $e$. Let $M^k(G)$ be the set of maximum-size $k$-allocations.
Consider an Erdos-Renyi random graph $G(m,p(m))$ with $m$ nodes, where between each node an undirected edge exists with probability $p(m)$ (and $p$ is a non-decreasing function). My question concerns the following: suppose we generate a graph $G(m,p(m))$, and then randomly draw a node $v$, edge $e \in G$, and allocations $A \in M^k(G)$ and $A' \in M^k(G\setminus e)$. What is the probability that $A(v) \neq A'(v)$? Denote this probability by $S(m)$. I'm really interested in the following question: Under what conditions does $S(m) \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$, and more importantly, what is the rate of convergence?
Yoshida and Zhou (2020) study a similar question, but do not discuss random graphs.

This seems like a strange question to ask if you want to understand sensitivity to edge deletion. If you just picked two random allocations $A, A' \in M^k(G)$, I would expect that's already often enough to have $A(v) \ne A'(v)$ with high probability, and we don't even need to delete the edge.

You may well be correct. Do you have a reference for the claim? If that's the case then I'd need to modify the question. One alternative would be to fix an algorithm for finding (perhaps approximate) maximum-size $k$-allocations, and then ask about the effect of deleting an edge on the output of this algorithm. This is closer in spirit to Yoshida and Zhou (2020).

Actually, let me be more precise: I expect $A(v) \ne A'(v)$ to hold whp for dense enough graphs only. Here is some of the calculation behind that. Let $p^(n)$ be the threshold for $G(n,p)$ to have a nearly-perfect $k$-allocation (with fewer than $k$ vertices uncovered). Then for $p \gg p^(n) \log n$, say, we can write $G(n,p)$ as the disjoint union of $\log n$ independent copies of $G(n,p')$ with $p' \gg p^*(n)$; each $G(n,p')$ whp has a nearly-perfect $k$-allocation, they are nearly disjoint, and so for most $v$, $\Pr[A(v)=A'(v)] \le \frac1{\log n}$.

So that is the story for dense-enough random graphs. (Actually, there are probably many more maximum $k$-allocations, so the true probability is probably much lower; this is just an upper bound.) On the other hand, consider triangles (for simplicity), and take $n^{-1} \ll p(n) \ll n^{-5/6}$. Here, there are many triangles in $G(n,p)$, but whp all of them are vertex-disjoint, and $M^3(G)$ actually contains only one allocation; conditioned on this whp event, $\Pr[A(v)=A'(v)] = 1$.
